# Why does Kuzen not have red eyes when wielding his kagune?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

I love *Tokyo Ghoul* and have the manga, but can someone please explain to me why Kuzen doesn't have red eyes when wielding his kagune in the anime?  Is it just a mistake made when animating this episode?

[image: Kuzen's normal eyes while wielding kagune]

Is this related with the fact that the manager always has his ghoul eyes in the later episodes?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, it's a mistake.

If it isn't, it could be a sign of weakness. Eyes manifest on extremely RC dense Kagunes like kakujas, and I believe the kakugan is when RC cells enter the eye and turn it black due to concentration.

Since his eyes aren't black while his Kagune is manifested, it means he doesn't have enough RC cells in his body to manifest Kakugan.